# How to refresh and object from a constructor

Tags: angularjs

I want to refresh my data object stored in `constructor` when it's changed. How can I do this? Currently, I have this:

HTML

```
    <dummy>
        <div ng-repeat="key in $ctrl.data">{{ key }}</div>
    </dummy>
```

JS(ES6):

```
class Dummy {
    constructor() {
        this.data = [];

        this.runData();
    }

    runData() {
        const inter = setInterval(() => {
            this.data.push('item');
            console.log(this.data);
        }, 1000);

        setTimeout(() => {
            clearInterval(inter);
        }, 5000);
    }
};

app.directive('dummy', () => {
    return {
        controller: Dummy,
        controllerAs: '$ctrl'
    };
});
```

I also tried writing a watcher:

```
app.directive('dummy', () => {
    return {
        controller: Dummy,
        controllerAs: '$ctrl',
        link(scope, el, a, ctrl) {
            scope.$watch(ctrl.data, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                ctrl.data = ctrl.data;
            }, true);
        }
    };
});
```

Console logs it good, but - as constructor is being run at the beginning - the view is empty. What can I do?

Comment: You can try using a `watcher` on the data you wish to keep an eyes on and then do some tasks if the value is changed.

Comment: I tried writing a '$watch' for it, but I didn't succeed. I've updated the code in my answer.

Comment: Can you make your code into a runnable example? Preferably with a jsfiddle or plunker link

Comment: http://codepen.io/tomekbuszewski/pen/JXReoV?editors=1011 code is here. Please note I'm still fighting with it, so it can change ;-)

Comment: I solved it using `scope.$apply()`, but I'm not sure if it's a good way. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know ES6, so kinda hard for me to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this. **I don't know if it's the best course of action, so if you think it's not, please write your own answer**. I used `$interval` service like this:

```
runData() {
    this.interval(() => {
        this.data.push(Date.now());
    }, 1000, 10);
}
```

Previously injecting it via `DI`, ofcourse.

I also had another attempt without the additional service. I used JS's `setInterval()` like this:

```
runData() {
  setInterval(() => { this.data.push(Date.now()); this.scope.$apply; }, 1000);
}
```

But in here I had to use `scope.$apply` excplicitly.

I think that the first example is better (cleaner), but both work.

Comment: Using angular's wrapper function for setInterval is the preferred approach here.